# validation in asp.net using validators

Tags: asp.net

i am using validator for validating blank textbox.
my problem is,i want to make the validation to false means the textbox can be blank,when i select Complete from dropdownlist.

How can i do this.

Comment: You can do this thing through your code.If you are interested  so i can send a code.

Answer (score 2):

You can [disable an ASP.NET validator using JavaScript](http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/08/11/87708.aspx). Tap into the `onchange` JavaScript event on your drop down list to invoke the disabling code, and that should do it.

Alternatively, if your combo box is posting back, you can disable or hide the validator in code behind by setting its `Visible` or `Enabled` property to `false`.

Comment: +1 Disabling validators using javascript makes better UI experiences & performance.

Answer (score 0):

Handle it in the dropdownlist change event, set the `Enabled` property of the validation control to `false`.

Or thru JavaScript set the validation control enabled to false. Note: Validation control must be set to `EnableClientScript=true`.